# Javascript "${status}" == 500 || ${status} == "undefined" failed in a while controller

Tags: javascript, testing, jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

I did a "while", which starts with a variable that was not previously defined, so I did the comparison:

`${__javaScript(${status} == "undefined",)}` and if the answer is
"true" the while loop starts and works; it runs once and gets the new status of the request, this time with a value of == 500 because I use a JSON extractor to get the new status returned in the API and then the API stops because the status is no longer undefined, now == 500, worked just fine. But

when I put one more validation using the "or" comparison:

```
${__javaScript("${status}" == 500 || ${status} == "undefined",)}
```

It should exit the loop if the response in the status field was different from "undefined" or "500", but when it returns "ERROR" it keeps running, I looked at the log and got the following error:

```
**2021-11-29 18:05:10,029 ERROR o.a.j.f.JavaScript: Error processing Javascript: ["ERROR" == 500 || ERROR == "undefined"]
javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "ERROR" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1**
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:454) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:406) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.JavaScript.executeWithNashorn(JavaScript.java:141) [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.JavaScript.execute(JavaScript.java:102) [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:138) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:113) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:100) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.WhileController.getCondition(WhileController.java:142) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.WhileController.endOfLoop(WhileController.java:62) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.WhileController.nextIsNull(WhileController.java:85) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:170) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.WhileController.next(WhileController.java:117) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:222) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:175) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:134) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:91) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:291) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
```

but like the "ERROR" isn't really meant to be set, because if it returns it's to exit the loop

so I really don't understand this error message, does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: Seems odd to use a variable before it is declared. What is the actual code? Why not defined it so it?

Comment: typeof status === "undefined" || status === 500

Comment: did you try to use `"${status}" == "undefined"` ?

Comment: "${status}" == "undefined"  

yes, tried that. I tried several variations already but it didn't work, when I didn't see how to try again I played here to see if anyone would know.

Comment: is that I'll only have the status after running the api, the api returns a status, like "500", or "Sucess" or "ERROR", and I had declared that while it was 500 it should continue running, but the api was inside of the loop then the loop didn't start because it didn't have the value of "status", and when I fixed "Status == 500" it's a variable before the loop, even when the status was updated inside the loop, it took the fixed value of the variable , not the new status, so I wanted to define that it would start even if that status had not yet been set.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax issue in the Javascript

Following will work within your while controller

```
${__javaScript("${status}" == "500" || "${status}" == "undefined",)}
```

Also [it's recommended](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) to use [__groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)  or [__jexl3](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) over Javascript considering performance.

> javaScript is not the best scripting language for performances in JMeter. If your plan requires a high number of threads it is advised to use __jexl3 or __groovy functions.

**Groovy**

```
${__groovy(vars.get("status")=="500" || vars.get("status")=="undefined",)}
```

**Jexl3**

```
${__jexl3(vars.get("status")=="500" || vars.get("status")=="undefined",)}
```

Comment: when I put it like that, the "undefined" in quotes doesn't even start running, I've already tested it.

Comment: I have pasted the statements from a tested script. It should work. Need to check.

Comment: DEBUG o.a.j.c.GenericController: Calling next on: class org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController
DEBUG o.a.j.t.p.AbstractProperty: Running version, executing function
DEBUG o.a.j.f.Groovy: __groovy(vars.get("status")=="500" || vars.get("status")=="undefined",)=false
 DEBUG o.a.j.c.WhileController: Condition string: 'false'
 DEBUG o.a.j.c.WhileController: Condition value: 'true'

Comment: DEBUG o.a.j.c.GenericController: Calling next on: class org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController
INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Grupo de Usuários- Fake Client - RecebeCallback 3-1
INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Grupo de Usuários- Fake Client - RecebeCallback 3-1
DEBUG o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Ending thread Grupo de Usuários- Fake Client - RecebeCallback 3-1

Comment: INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
DEBUG o.a.j.v.ViewResultsFullVisualizer: Expanded: [[Root]]
 DEBUG o.a.j.v.ViewResultsFullVisualizer: Elements: [Root]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a copy-paste issue:

```
${__javaScript("${status}" == 500 || ${status} == "undefined",)}
               ^         ^           ^       ^
                 here you have       ^ and here 
                 quotation marks     you don't
```

it also makes sense to surround this `500` with quotation marks as well otherwise you can get an unexpected behaviour trying compare a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

All [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) with their respective values can be visualized using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination.

Comment: when I put it like that, the "undefined" in quotes doesn't even start running, I've already tested it.

I really have a problem, because in isolation the == 500 comparison works when I put it in quotes, and the "undefined" comparison when I put it in quotes doesn't work.

Comment: Please read Dmitri, comment carefully the quotes should be on ${status} not on undefined, and undefined is a returned value you shouldn't put it in quotes, try something like "${status}" == undefined